# play 2.4 connect to remote database

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm new to play and scala, Using latest play 2.4.x. I want to connect to mysql through remote ip with the following configuration

In application.conf

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://10.0.1.32:3306/scala_test_db"
db.default.username="scalauser"
db.default.password="test"
```

In build.sbt

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36"
```

But jdbc is trying to connect to my local IP. Following is the error I got

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'scalauser'@'10.0.0.224'
```

Can anyone help me how to connect to remote IP?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks fine. The error message told you that the *mysql user* 'scalauser'@'10.0.0.224' has no access. That means your app is connecting to the Database from 10.0.0.224.

I guess you only need to add a new Database user.

```
GRANT USAGE ON scala_test_db.* TO 'scalauser'@'10.0.0.224';
FLUSH privileges;
```

Check the MySQL docs:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html

Comment: No, Thats not the issue. i'm trying to connect to 10.0.1.32(db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://10.0.1.32:3306/scala_test_db") but its taking 10.0.0.224 as host.

Comment: The error message you're providing tells you nothing about the database host JDBC is connecting to. As I already mention in the answer the error message comes from the database server and says that the MySQL User 'scalauser'@'10.0.0.224' has no access to the db.